# Retrieving query string parameters in Slim Framework 3

Tags: slim

I have a `get` route in the form

```
$app->get('/redirect[/{subject}]', function ($request, $response, $args) {

});
```

If I make a request to `/redirect/server?site=local&name=john`

I can get the `subject` right with

```
$request->getAttribute('subject')
```

However, I can't get the query parameters. If I inspect `$request->getQueryParams()` I get:

```
[
  '/redirect/server?site' => 'local',
  'name' => 'john'
]
```

Whereas I'd be expecting the query params to be

```
[
  'site' => 'local',
  'name' => 'john'
]
```

What am I doing wrong? Perhaps I should specify that the url parameter mustn't accept a question mark?

**Edit 1**

I've been asked to post my webserver config. I'll have access to that dev machine tomorrow, so this is just a reminder to myself to add said info. **However** @jmattheis already gave me a hint.

[Slim Framework 3 setup for nginx](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html#nginx-configuration) says something along the lines

```
location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

Whereas I'm using the rewrite snippet that used to be suggested for slim 2 at some point in time:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
    }
```

This config has worked fine for me for years, but it happens that I've never tried to parse whatever came after the question mark. It is just now that I have forked an abandoned project that I'm trying to transform raw `$_REQUEST` parsing into Slim routing methods.

**Edit 2**

The codebase for the project is in the repo [phpPgAdmin6](https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/phpPgAdmin6). It's basically a fork of [phpPgAdmin](https://github.com/phppgadmin/phppgadmin) that had no route logic, so I'm trying to centralize requests and responses to a given extent, and parse the query string using Slim native methods.

Comment: Which slim version, for me it all works as expected.

Comment: Version 3.8.1, I'm running the app in a subfolder of the document's root, but that shouldn't make a difference, should it?

Comment: Please post your .htaccess file

Comment: Please let us know more about your application directory structure and contents of .htaccess file.
And as a side note, you can use `$args['subject']` instead of `$request->getAttribute('subject')`

Comment: @jmattheis I'm running nginx. But you gave me a hint right there. I was using a setup that's different from the one suggested in slim docs

Comment: @Nima there, I posted the codebase. I'm using `$args` already, I experimented with `$request` methods just to try to find out how to grab the query string args.

Comment: @jmattheis that was it. The `try files` directive was using `$request_uri` instead of `$is_args$args`. Now it works as expected. Please make an answer to this question stating that error so I can mark it as resolved. It would feel wrong to answer my own question when your comment was the one that pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out you need to use

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Instead of

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
}
```

The second one adds the whole request uri as a query parameter that would result in something like this

```
index.php?/redirect/server?site=local&name=john
```

because of that `/redirect/server?site` was given as query-key.

Comment: Yeah, thanks to your comment I noticed this flaw. Of course Slim doesn't complain about this when it comes to named parameters, but the query string itself behaves really different now. I was even exploding ` $request->getUri()->getQuery()` with the question mark to get the query string. Now I don't need that anymore! Thank you!